# How to Plot (show) user location on Image? iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, geolocation

So here is task i need to get done on iOS:

Show User's Current Location on an Image like this:

[image]

Yes, like this Image!

So few things one will notice as soon as one look at it. Its Tilted. It's headings are Off. You can see horizon..!

Lets say,

- I have location coordinates for corners of this image.
- I have angle at which this image is tilted. (e.g 50°)
- I have heading angle of the image. (e.g -170° North, which means its about 10° South-West, correct me if im wrong.)
- And i have Zoom level on which this image would have been zoomed if it was on Google Maps/Google Earth. (e.g 14 zoom level - out of 20)

But thats the task, i need to show users location on such images. Just like in "Google Earth".

Can anyone give me heads up to accomplish this task?

Thank you everyone. :)

Comment: What are the location coordinates of the corners of your example image ?  Can you show us the numbers.  I'd suggest dropping terms such as -170° North too, and stick to using angular measurement only in stating azimuth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information you have, sounds like you can use [line-plane intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-plane_intersection) to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the desired result by plotting the coordinate on a UIView and transform it using [CATrasnform3D](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/Reference/reference.html). These explanations also help, [Explanation of Transformation Matrix](http://milen.me/technical/core-animation-3d-model/) in terms of Core Animation and [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html) itself.

```
_graphic.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-2.89724656);

CATransform3D rotatedTransform = _graphic.layer.transform;

rotatedTransform.m34 = 1.0 / 500;
rotatedTransform.m22 = -2;
rotatedTransform.m41 = 170;
rotatedTransform.m42 = 170;

rotatedTransform = 
CATransform3DRotate(rotatedTransform, 
                    51 * M_PI / 180.0f, 
                    1.0f, 
                    0.0f, 
                    0.0f);


_graphic.layer.transform = rotatedTransform;

[_graphic setNeedsDisplay];
```

Thank you all.